# Creating "issue" button to report state at end of last request/response cycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, logging, error-handling, rubygems

I am adding an issue button to my site.  My intent is to allow the user to report an issue they have had in use of the site.  This would be a usability issue, as I already trap and report actual failures.  Currently, the button simply collects a textual response and writes an a SQL record in my XLog.  I could show you that code, but it means nearly nothing in terms of the larger question.

What I really would like to do is collect as much as I can of the state that was current at the end of the last request/response cycle.  I plan on emailing this state to my support team using Action Mailer.  I know I can gather the standard ($...) global variables, at minimum.  However, I would like more than that.

It would be very nice to go so far as to grab a screenshot of the screen where the button was clicked.  At minimum, I'd like to know the URL, state of all the variables, etc.  I'd go so far as to raise and trap an error to do this.  However, even that would occur at the start of the next request.

I have considered creating an after_action for every controller action that would store the state.  That may be heavy handed, but I don't know if I have another choice.  Or, if even that would be enough but it likely would.

In any case, I often find that when I work on a particularly difficult question, there is a gem for that.  Is there a gem for that?  Or, can someone show me the starting point on this tangled ball of twine?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having heard no response, I decided to try this and see what happens.  It gives me some basic information.  I'd be happy to hear any suggestions.

In my application controller, I have:

```
  before_action :gather_response
  after_action  :gather_request
  helper_method :gather_request
  helper_method :gather_response
```

...

```
private 

  def gather_request
    session[:kac_debug] = Hash.new if session[:kac_debug].blank?
    session[:kac_debug][:request_trace] = Array.new if session[:kac_debug][:request_trace].blank?
    session[:kac_debug][:request_request] = request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
    session[:kac_debug][:request_trace] =
        session[:kac_debug][:request_trace].unshift("#{request["controller"]}, #{request["action"]}").take(12)
    true
  end

  def gather_response
    session[:kac_debug] = Hash.new if session[:kac_debug].blank?
    session[:kac_debug][:response_request] = response.request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
    session[:kac_debug][:response_status]  = response.status
    true
  end
```

In the controller where I gather and report the information, I want to ensure that the information isn't overwritten, so I have:

```
  before_action :gather_response, except: [:new, :create]
  after_action :gather_request, except: [:new, :create]
```

First impression is that it seems to be doing what I want.  I haven't done extensive debugging using it yet, however.  I may need to add more information.  But, I want to keep it to the minimal amount that I need to understand what was happening before the user issued the report.  I may need more, or less...

Advice desired.  Thanks.